# How can I rotate the Player (cube) on mobile only one part of the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't how to rotate the player if i touch the screen and move my finger in one part of the screen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4FTP.jpg This is the part where I want to rotate the cube.

Comment: Please review the how-to-ask guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

add a script to the cube, something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.touches > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 pos = touch.position;
        float width_fraction = pos.x / (float)Screen.width;

        // only run this, if finger is on the right half (50%)
        if(width_fraction > 0.5)
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, Time.deltatime * 30f, 0); // rotate 30 Deg per second
        }
    }
}
```